# shiny R either or filter with two inputs

Tags: r, shiny, filtering

I created a shiny app and want to implement an "either or" filter.

Let's say everything is preselected, so the table displays completely. If I select one filter, than the other filter is dismissed/ignored/nulled/...

For example I'm selecting 'gears' = 3 and 'carb' is nulled. Than I'm adding 'gears' = 4. After that I'm selecting 'carb' = 1 and the the 'gear' filter is nulled.

Maybe someone can help me with it. I'm wrapping my head around this problem. I think I need to use `reactive` or `eventReactive` or some other kind of `reactive`-expression. But maybe someone here has an idea.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

data(mtcars)
allcarbs <- sort(unique(mtcars$carb))
allgears <- sort(unique(mtcars$gear))

ui <- fluidPage(

  pickerInput(inputId = "carbinput",
              label = h4("carb"),
              choices = allcarbs,
              selected = allcarbs,
              multiple = TRUE, options = list('actions-box' = TRUE)),

  h4("or"),

  pickerInput(inputId = "gearinput", 
              label = h4("gears"), 
              choices = allgears, 
              selected = allgears, 
              multiple = TRUE, options = list('actions-box' = TRUE)),

  tableOutput("mtcarstab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mtcarstab <- renderTable({
    subset(mtcars, 
           gear %in% as.numeric(input$gearinput) |
             carb %in% as.numeric(input$carbinput))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple solution:

before declaring server or UI, create reactive values

`vals=reactiveValues(carb=FALSE,gear=FALSE)`

then you can use observeEvent to change them on your server:

```
observeEvent(input$gearinput,{
vals$gear=TRUE
vals$carb=FALSE
})

observeEvent(input$carbinput,{
vals$gear=FALSE
vals$carb=TRUE
})

mytable=eventReactive(c(vals$gear,vals$carb,input$carb,input$gear),{
if(vals$carb){return(subset(mtcars, 
           carb %in% as.numeric(input$carbinput)))}
else{return(subset(mtcars, 
           gear %in% as.numeric(input$gearinput)))}
})

  output$mtcarstab <- renderTable({
    mytable()
  })
```

**EDIT:**
I edited the comments into the answer, to make it 100% correct.

Comment: This is very helpful. I did not know about reactiveValues outside `ui` and `server`. But it only solves 80%. It changes the filterinput only when I switch between `input$carbinput` and `input$gearinput`. When I, e.g. select number 4 in gear, then the table changes, When I add 3, id doesn't change anymore. I guess adding a value is not counted as an event and the `observerEvent(input$gearinput` does not fire

Comment: just adding to reactiveEvent c(vals$gear,vals$carb,input$carb,input$gear) solves the problem, right?

Comment: That works like a charm. But why is that? `eventReactive()` reacts to multiple changes and `observerEvent` is not?

Comment: both react to changes in what is inside its arguments. Note the difference between what is inside the observers and eventReactive. You could, for example, declare multiple triggers to observeEvent, like `observeEvent(c(arg1,arg2),{do(this)})`.

Comment: This no longer works as expected. Only the first observeEvent() call will be responded to first. The other has to be modified second for some reason. The table doesn't update if you add or remove selections from within the same input list, you have to bounce back and forth between inputs to get the output to change.